# AngularJS $q.all for all queries in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple queries in one controller, that load while the controller is loading (and after I click on some elements)

```
var d = $q.defer();
$scope.userOrders = UserOrders.query({id:$routeParams.id}, function(result) {
   d.resolve(result);

});
$q.all([d.promise]).then(function(response){
   $('#loading').hide();
});
```

How i can write this only once, not in each controller?

Comment: you can wrap it using `service` or `factory` modules.

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate your ajax logic in a service

```
var services = angular.module('myServices', []);

services.factory('AjaxLoader', ['$q', function($q) {

    return {
        doAjax : function() {
           var d = $q.defer();
           $scope.userOrders = UserOrders.query({id:$routeParams.id}, function(result) {
               d.resolve(result);
           });

           $q.all([d.promise]);
        }
    }
});
```

In your controller.

```
var controllers = angular.module('myControllers',[]);

controllers.controller('Controller', ['AjaxLoader', function(AjaxLoader) {
    AjaxLoader.doAjax().then(function() {
          $("#loading").hide();
    });
}]);
```